# Cannot connect native facebook via proxy in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, proxy

I am using a proxy when using facebook, but it turns out that I cannot connect to facebook server when using native app, but it works fine when I use browser in mobile.
What I can see is native facebook connect to FB server directly without proxy, but other apps will connect proxy server first.
BTW, I think login is ok but fetch content is not, I can see graph.facebook.com visit my proxy but others not.

Is there a way that I can use native FB with proxy?